# How to use update query in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

hi am very new to hibernate and could anybody plz help me out how to use update query to upadte the record of the table ...i am using like this in dao class

```
  Session ses = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Transaction tx = ses.beginTransaction();
        Query q = ses.createQuery("from RegisterPojo  where email =:email");
        q.setParameter("email", bean.getEmail());
        RegisterPojo pojo = (RegisterPojo) q.list().get(0);
        pojo.setUname(bean.getUname());
        ses.update(pojo);
        tx.commit();
        ses.flush();
        ses.close();
```

Hi i have edited my code from this am getting exception as, Could not execute JDBC batch update

thanks in advance

Comment: hi could anybody plz help me out!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `update` on the hibernate session

Observe the following example

```
Query q = session.createQuery("from RegisterPojo where email =:email");
q.setParameter("email", "Fred@Example.com");
RegisterPojo  pojo= (RegisterPojo)q.list().get(0);

pojo.setName("Fred");
session.update(pojo);
```

Comment: Because the above syntax is for getting a list from a query as in `select * from employees`

Comment: here I could not understand what is the table name

Comment: Now the query is executing fine but the data is not updating in table

Comment: In that case you probably need a transaction which will need commiting as in `tx = session.beginTransaction();`

Comment: OK - does it work?  You may want to wrap the code in a try/catch and only do the commit if no exceptions otherwise rollback

Comment: am getting exception as Could not execute JDBC batch update from the above code